# if a series of polynomial converge uniformally locally, and each of then has only real roots, then if f is an entire, then has only real roots.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, uniform-convergence, entire-functions

let $P_N$ be a series of polynomial that has only real roots, which converges uniformly locally. let the function f be the function they converge into, And let's assume that f is an entire function.
A) prove that f has only real roots (if it is not the 0 function).
B) let $f^{(k)}$  be not the zero function. Prove then that $f^{(k)}$ has only real roots.

Comment: Hurwitz theorem for point 1 and same plus Rolle (which shows that $P_N^{(k)}$ have only real roots as long as they are not constant) for the second point; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: @Conrad I tend to disagree, Hurwitz theorem regards only to compact sets. R is not a compact set.

Comment: pick a non-real zero of $f$ and a small compact neighborhood of it disjoint from the real axis and apply Hurwitz there to get a contradiction - Hurwitz is a local theorem