$1 + z + \frac{z^2}{4} + \frac{z^3}{4^3} + \frac{z^4}{4^6} + \frac{z^5}{4^{10}} +... = 0$ implies $Im(z) = 0$?
Consider the triangular numbers $1,3,6,10,15,...$
It appears that
$B(z) = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{4} + \frac{z^3}{4^3} + \frac{z^4}{4^6} + \frac{z^5}{4^{10}} +... = 0$ implies $Im(z) = 0$ ?
How to prove that ?
$B(z)$ is clearly an entire function.
And $|B(z)|$ grows relatively slowly with respect to $|z|$.
Slower than $\exp(2+\ln(1+|4z|)^3)$ at least.
(Notice the max modulus principle shows that the direction of the positive real line dominates)
Thus we conclude this function is entire and completely determined by its zero's. This follows from the fact that it grows much slower than exponential on the complex plane and theorems like Weierstrass factorization theorem and Hadamard factorization theorem.
In fact it seems true for any nonconstant taylor polynomial of $B(z)$, for instance :
$1 + z + \frac{z^2}{4} + \frac{z^3}{4^3} + \frac{z^4}{4^6} = 0$ implies $Im(z) = 0$
How to prove that ?
I was not able to find proofs online. Nor how to start such a proof.
And I have no practical exact closed form for all the zero's, if that even exists. If I had I might be able to set up a system of equations to show it.

Why would $B(z)$ grow that slowly as you claimed? Along the positive real line $B(z)$ grows at least as fast as any polynomial [eventually]. For example, $B(z) > z^5/4^{10}$ for positive real $z$. What am I missing here

how many $n$'s have you checked $\text{Im} z = 0$ for the finite truncate polynomials? That does seem interesting if true.

what motivates this conjecture?

$$B(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{2^{k(k-1)}}$$

@Conrad my mentor wrote it. It has to do with approximating analytic functions with entire functions. Or vice versa ; getting estimates on growth rates for given entire taylor series.  Here is a link :  https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/special-polynomials
and
https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/fake-function-theory
And the first origin was for finding entire approximations for the half-iterate of the exponential ( tetration ideas )  Sheldon Levenstein worked on it too.
The post is recent and the google site is in version 1.0 only

@Conrad  for those intrested in the tetration version used for that half-exp : https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/fake-function-theory/pictures-of-fakesemi-expx
https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/tetration
for what its worth.

@Mike : see the links and take into account that $B'(z) > B(z/4) $ but way closer to $C'(z) = C(z/4) $ than to $\exp ' (z) = \exp(z)$

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43626/sheldon-l  ( same Sheldon )

@Conrad besides zero's on a line is a typical math thingy right ? Riemann would agree.

This question is similar to: Show all roots of $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{k(n-k)} x^k$ are real (December 6, 2014 Putnam problem). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

From the above problem, your original problem follows from this fact in complex analysis https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785254/if-a-series-of-polynomial-converge-uniformally-locally-and-each-of-then-has-onl

This answer points to some resources, and mentions how they relate to the given situation. The links give more than i know, more than i can say here.
Let us define $c_k$ for $k\ge 0$ to be the coefficients of the given analytic function $f(z)=\sum c_kz^k$:
$$
c_k=2^{-k(k-1)}\ .
$$

There is a first related paper,
[K] Kurtz, A sufficient condition for all the roots of a polynomial to be real, AMM, 1992 (99, no. 3), pages 259–263.
It shows that for a polynomial with positive real coefficients, satisfying
$$ p(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0\ ,\qquad 
a_k^2> 4a_{k-1}a_{k+1}\ ,$$
all the roots are real.
This is "almost enough" for our case, the arguments are simple.
(And it makes us comfortable with the powers of $4$ that appear in the given function $f(z)$.)

There is a theorem of Hutchinson, published a century ago, marked only with an A in usual font:
[H] Hutchinson, On a remarkable class of entire functions, Trans. AMS, 1923, (25), pages 325–332.
Consider $f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kz^k$ with positive coefficients $a_k>0$ so that the quotients
$$
\frac{a_k^2}{a_{k-1}a_{k+1}}
$$
are all $\ge 4$. Then this is equivalent to:

(i) the zeros of $f(z)$ are all simple, real, negative, and
(ii) the zeros of the partial sum polynomials $\sum_{M\le k\le N}a_kz^k, M<N$ are all real, and $\le 0$.

This is already our case, since
$$
\frac{c_k^2}{c_{k-1}c_{k+1}}
=\frac{2^{-k(k-1)}}{2^{-(k+1)k-(k-1)(k-2)}}
= 2^{(k^2+k)+(k^2-3k+2)-2(k^2-k)}
=2^2=4\ .
$$

Can we do better? Yes, the quotient $4$ can be improved, see the following article published in June 2022
[BNV] Bielenova, Nazarenko, Vishnyakova, A sufficient condition for a complex polynomial... arXiv 2207.08108
(It also cites Hutchinson, Theorem A, and gives further references.)
Here, the $4$ is improved to the value $b_\infty\approx 4.8105828$ which is the unique root $x>$ of
$$
\frac 12 = \sum_{k\ge 1} x^{-k^2/2}\ .
$$
The R.H.S. is an increasing function, so taking partial sums, then zeros for the associated equation gives a monotone sequence converging to $b_\infty$. If we stop in $1$, so solve $\frac 12=x^{-1/2}$ we get the solution $4$. If we stop at the next step, then get $\frac 12=x^{-1/2}+x^{-2}$, the polynomial $Y^4+Y-\frac 12$ has the only positive root $Y_1\approx0.4565526370148526\dots$
So the corresponding $x$-value is $x_1=Y_1^{-2}\approx 4.797536514160166\dots$ which is a good improvement of "the four".

The reference  **[BNV] ** was published in Mathematical Inequalities & Applications which is an  Open Access Journal and can be downloaded freely.   See https://mia.ele-math.com/26-06/A-sufficient-condition-for-a-complex-polynomial-to-have-only-simple-zeros-and-an-analog-of-Hutchinson-s-theorem-for-real-polynomials

What I don't get is that $4.8$ is not an improvement since $x > 4.8 \implies x > 4$. So a smaller value would be an improvement. I think you misread the paper, using the constant $4.8...$ gives another conclusion from another assumption.

I think the $4.8105828$ constant in your last linked paper is about simple zero's but not necc real zero's.  it seems the condition real is added to the condition simple and that gives $4$. But I am not sure. Now I wonder what the condition is for real but possible not simple ...  Then again 4.8 > 4 which is not logical in this context ... confused
